# LESS not outputting source map

Tags: css, less

I just installed less and trying to get a css and map file generated. Whatever tutorial I find, it never works. Here's an example of a tutorial I've been following, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-less-and-the-chrome-devtools--net-36636.

My less file is this:

```
 @color: black;

body {
  background-color: @color;
}

.text{
color: @color;
}
```

And the command that I use to compile is this:

```
lessc -source-map=header.map header.less header.css
```

I've also tried

```
lessc header.less header.css
lessc -source-map=header.map header.less header.css
```

in case I needed to generate the css for whatever reason and

```
lessc --source-map-less-inline header.less header.css
```

to see if I can generate it inline, but that doesn't work either.

The version of less that I am using is **lessc 1.4.2 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]** on an **Ubuntu** server.

Comment: 1.4.2 is too old version for proper source-map support (it shoud be minimum [1.5.0](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150), but in fact 1.7.x or 2.x.x are almost the must).

Comment: Thanks seven-phases-max. I just used apt-get to install less. That means I'll probably have to uninstall and use the npm way. You should post as answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

follow this link. I use it to install LESS on ubuntu.

after it is done, then just use the following command to compile a less file into css.

```html
lessc theme.less theme.css
```

[**Link to refer**](http://www.onurguzel.com/install-less-on-ubuntu-with-npm/)